# Bypass popup using Scrapy (yummy ice-cream)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, popup

I'm trying to scrape ice cream-related data from the website, https://threetwinsicecream.com/products/ice-cream/. It seems to be a pretty straightforward website to scrape. However, I can't get my spider to work owing - I think - to a (JavaScript) popup that is obstructing my access. I've enclosed a condensed version of my scrapy code below:

```
class NutritionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nutrition'
    allowed_domains = ['threetwinsicecream.com']
    start_urls = ['http://threetwinsicecream.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//div[@id='pints']/div[2]/div")
        for product in products:
            name = product.xpath(".//a/p/text()").extract_first()
            link = product.xpath(".//a/@href").extract_first()

            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link,
                callback=self.parse_products,
                meta={
                    "name": name,
                    "link": link
                }
            )

    def parse_products(self, response):
        name = response.meta["name"]
        link = response.meta["link"]

        serving_size = response.xpath("//div[@id='nutritionFacts']/ul/li[1]/text()").extract_first() 

        calories = response.xpath("//div[@id='nutritionFacts']/ul/li[2]/span/text()").extract_first()

        yield {
            "Name": name,
            "Link": link,
            "Serving Size": serving_size,
            "Calories": calories
        }
```

I've devised a workaround, but it involves manually writing out all of the links to the various ice-cream varieties like below. I've also tried disabling JavaScript on the website, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
def parse(self, response):

        urls = [
            "https://threetwinsicecream.com/products/ice-cream/madagascar-vanilla/",
            "https://threetwinsicecream.com/products/ice-cream/sea-salted-caramel/",
            ...
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse_products
            )

def parse_products(self, response):
        pass
```

Is there a way to bypass the popup using scrapy, or do I have to use some other tool like selenium? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi there! I doubt that the problem is the JS-popup, since Scrapy can't execute JS without Selenium, Splash or something similar. Could you please post the output you're getting from the spider?

Comment: when calling a new page, selenium resets the old information so the links you previously received are no longer available, As a workaround, you can print it into the TXT file and import it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spider you posted works. At least on my machine. The only thing I had to change was `start_urls = ['http://threetwinsicecream.com/']` to `start_urls = ['https://threetwinsicecream.com/products/ice-cream/']`

If you run into these kinds of problems you can use Scrapys `open_in_browser` function with which you can see what Scrapy sees in your browser. It's documented [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#open-in-browser)

Comment: My mistake! I convinced myself that the problem was due to the popup when it was actually something a lot more simple. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. I make this kind of mistake multiple times a day, spend hours on it and then call it work, so...